# vim and python scripts debugging

Tags: python, vim

Are there any ways to debug python scripts not leaving vim in *nix systems (executing the script, setting up breakpoints, showing variables in watch-list, etc)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html):

```
import pdb
def main():
  list = [1,2,3]
  pdb.set_trace()
  list = [2,3,4]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now run using `:!python %` and you'll hit your breakpoint and be able to debug interactively like in [gdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger).

Comment: theres also ipdb which is a little ipython like, so more user friendly.

Comment: I'm getting [this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914704/bdbquit-raised-when-debugging-python)

Answer (score 8):

As of Python 3.7, you can use `breakpoint()` builtin without importing anything.

Built-in `breakpoint()` calls `sys.breakpointhook()`. By default, the latter imports `pdb` and then calls `pdb.set_trace()`

Inheriting code from [Pierre-Antoine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135360/pierre-antoine-lafayette)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1902220/939986), the code would look like this:

```
def main():
  list = [1,2,3]
  breakpoint()
  list = [2,3,4]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

<sub>Source: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-553-built-in-breakpoint</sub>

Answer (score 7):

Try [pyclewn](http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/). It allows to use vim as front end for pdb. You can create/delete break points, control flow of debugging process, look at values of your variables. All from vim!

Comment: It says it's not being developed any more.

Answer (score 7):

Also try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb - its like pdb but more advanced. Contains code highlighting, stack, showing avaliable values, etc. Not only-vim solution but for me works perfectly.

Three Steps:

Install:

> pip install pudb

Paste set_trace in code

> from pudb import set_trace; set_trace()

Run your code

Answer (score 4):

As 2020 the Debugger Adapter Protocol is taken care by [vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector#installation).
Supporting Cpp, Python, Java, Js, Go ...
See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674780/2544873)

Answer (score 2):

The [vimpdb](https://github.com/gotcha/vimpdb) plugin integrates the Python debugger `pdb` into the VIM editor.

I do recommend it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Vim and pdb-clone is the combination I use. I use [Home - pyclewn](http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/) which provides a replacement for pdb called pdb-clone that is quite faster than vanilla pdb. It integrates well with vim via a plugin, and the thing I appreciate most is that it takes care of breakpoints outside the code, not setting traces within, thus not messing up my line numbers. It does not have a watch window for python yet. You might have a look at [vim-debug](https://github.com/jaredly/vim-debug) too, which I could not get to work with my existing highlighting setup.

Answer (score 0):

See the "Debugging" section in [this](http://www.sontek.net/category/Vim.aspx) blog post. It shows how to setup F7 to set breakpoints and Shift+F7 to remove breakpoints. It also uses `pdb`, as mentioned before. With a little modification, you can replace the use of `pdb` with `ipdb` (`pdb` using [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/)), which is a lot nicer to use.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you want to use VIM as a Python IDE.

A quick Google search found [this](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/05/24/vim-as-python-ide/) and [this](http://dancingpenguinsoflight.com/2009/02/python-and-vim-make-your-own-ide/) example, with many more.

EDIT: Well, Ok, it seems likely you've searched more than I have.

I hope someone else has some ideas.

Comment: I've already read this article. The VimPDB mentioned there didn't work for me and gets broken each time i tried to use it.

Answer (score -4):

From what I know, there is one more option: You could use Eclipse + PyDev for project managing and Vim as an editor for Eclipse. That way You could use the best of both worlds.

Also, I haven't tried it, but You could try [this script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2270).